# Storing daily yield curve data in SQL table

Tags: sql-server, rdbms

I have daily yield curve data for integer maturities that should be stored in a MSSQL server.

### Currency.csv

Currently, the data is stored in CSV files per currency in the format:

```
date, 1y, 2y, 3y, ...
08/12/2020, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, ...
```

I am wondering what the best choice for a table would be.

### Same Format Table

The current data could be directly translated to a table with columns:

```
+------------+------+------+------+------+
|    date    |  1y  |  2y  |  3y  |  ... |
+------------+------+------+------+------+
| 08/12/2020 |  0.4 |  0.5 |  0.6 |  ... |
+------------+------+------+------+------+
```

### Alternate Table Design

However, I could also store it like:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
|    date    |  currency |  maturity |  value |
+------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| 08/12/2020 |  "EUR"    |         1 |    0.4 |
| 08/12/2020 |  "EUR"    |         2 |    0.5 |
| 08/12/2020 |  "EUR"    |         3 |    0.6 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

Obviously, the second approach would take more space than the first, but I would see the advantage that I am not restricting the value of the maturity in case in the future it should be changed to non-integer values or to maturities that don't have a column yet.

Which of the two table designs would be better? Are there other designs that would fit better?

Comment: As you can see, both "work". Which is better depends wholly on how the data will be used and what the constraints are. If you want to [normalize the data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), the second is more ideal. If you're just planning on ingesting it into R for analysis, the former may be preferable. We don't know because we lack context.

Comment: The data will mostly be read (and not updated) by applications that further process it, be it for some statistical analysis or recurring reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second choice (long) is preferable for the reasons you outline, provided you use the right keys and constraints.

Something like this is probably in the right direction:

```
CREATE TABLE Currency
(
  CurrencyCd    CHAR(3)      NOT NULL  /* This is the ISO currency code */
 ,CurrencyDesc  VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Currency PRIMARY KEY (CurrencyCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT AK_Currency UNIQUE (CurrencyDesc)
 ,CONSTRAINT CK_CurrencyCd_Length CHECK (LEN(CurrencyCd) = 3)
)
GO

/* This is solely to prevent invalid values being added */
CREATE TABLE MaturityAge
(
  MaturityAgeYr  TINYINT  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Maturity PRIMARY KEY (MaturityAgeYr)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE CurrencyYield
(
  CurrencyCd     CHAR(3)       NOT NULL
 ,MaturityAgeYr  TINYINT       NOT NULL  /* Possibly consider using months if finer detail possible */
 ,AsOfDt         DATE          NOT NULL
 ,Yield          DECIMAL(9,1)  NOT NULL /* Can increase decimal precision if necessary */
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_CurrencyYield_Of_Currency FOREIGN KEY (CurrencyCd) REFERENCES Currency (CurrencyCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_CurrencyYield_At_Maturity FOREIGN KEY (MaturityAgeYr) REFERENCES MaturityAge (MaturityAgeYr)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_CurrencyYield PRIMARY KEY (CurrencyCd, AsOfDt, MaturityAgeYr)
)
GO
```

Here the choice of the composite clustered index form by the primary key `(CurrencyCd, AsOfDt, MaturityAgeYr)` ensures the data will be (more or less) stored sorted according to those columns.  That means any queries of the type `WHERE CurrencyCd = 'EUR'` will only read the relevant pages.

This choice of clustered index + storing the data in a "long" format will make "widening" the data trivial - so if you need to view the data as you provide in the first example, it's a simple `PIVOT`.

Other considerations:

- If the volume of data is very large, but most of the values do not change, you can explore only storing changed values.  It takes a little more code to retrieve the data for a given date, but you can create date tables/views to simplify that.  If this is the case, let me know in the comments and I'll expand my answer.
- Over time the table will fragment (a large number of records will not be co-located according to the clustered index), so the clustered index will need to be rebuilt occasionally.  There are a number of readily available tools/scripts to make this relatively simple.